# Method Select (run-time error 1004)

Tags: vba, excel, select, runtime-error, offset

I want to find a certain cell and insert a value (copied from another book) in a cell offset from a given cell .
I wrote the code but the error pops up

> run time error 1004 select method range class failed

In the code row:  `r.Offset(6, 5).Select`

```
Sub связатьцифирь3()

    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim book2 As Workbook
    Dim r As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Решение\цифирь.xlsx")
    Set book2 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 4\БАЗА ДАННЫХ\прошлый сезон\Англия\1-ое место\54.xlsx")
    'переходим в активную страницу откуда надо скопировать данные'
     book2.Worksheets("54").Activate
     Range("AP100").Copy

    'ищемс
    With book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("A1:CV808")

        Set r = .Find(What:="54")
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = r.Address
            Do
               'условие для страны
               If r.Offset(3, 0).Text = "Англия" Then
                   r.Offset(6, 5).Select
                   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
               End If            
               Set r = .FindNext(r)             
           Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With  

End Sub
```

Comment: not sure why you are getting this error, but why do you use `Select` ? why not just use `r.Offset(6, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado the error is because at that moment the active WB is `book2`. But of course, as you said there's no need to `Select` here.

Comment: Thank you . Now programm works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to `Activate` the `book2.Worksheets("54")`, and later `r.Offset(6, 5).Select` and again use `Selection`, you should try to keep the `Copy` >> `Paste` as close as you can:

```
book2.Worksheets("54").Range("AP100").Copy
r.Offset(6, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

**Code**

```
Sub связатьцифирь3()

    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim book2 As Workbook
    Dim r As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Решение\цифирь.xlsx")
    Set book2 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 4\БАЗА ДАННЫХ\прошлый сезон\Англия\1-ое место\54.xlsx")

    'ищемс
    With book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("A1:CV808")

        Set r = .Find(What:="54")
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = r.Address
            Do
                'условие для страны
                If r.Offset(3, 0).Value2 = "Англия" Then
                    book2.Worksheets("54").Range("AP100").Copy
                    r.Offset(6, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
                Set r = .FindNext(r)
           Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select range in an inactive worksheet, this is the reason.
  Try activating it first or do as Shai suggested.